# SSRS External Image from URL Displays in visual studio, not on server

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to show images in SSRS based on a URL. Everything works great in Visual Studio when I preview, but when I publish the report, the images are totally blank--not even giving the little red "X".

I can display embedded images just fine, but external images from URLs show up blank.

My images are publicly hosted, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue. Here's an example of a hosted image:
https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_bb363d73-5c1f-4178-8702-7a5a0e26d19e.jpg

Most of the solutions I've seen consist of saving the images to a file and then referencing the filepath (here's one: [SSRS - How to show external image based on URL inside column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380961/ssrs-how-to-show-external-image-based-on-url-inside-column)).

Is my problem a firewall issue? If so, how do I find the firewall to make my images show up on the Server?

Right-clicking on where the image should appear shows there is an image there (see below), but when I actually click the link it returns a tiny white square (see second pic).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Right click on the image in the published report and check the URL

Comment: I updated the question to include what I see after right-clicking on the image.